# how to formulate the following properties formally?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let (N, E, l), be a labeled directed graph, where N is a set of vertices, E ⊆ N×N is a set of edges, and l: E → L is a function assigning labels from a set L to edges. Let source and target be functions on E such that source(s, t) = s and target(s, t) = t. Formulate the following properties formally:

1. Every label in L is a label of some edge.
2. There are no nodes that are targets of more than two edges with identical
   labels.
3. There is at least one path of length three where all the edges have identical
   labels.
4. There are no nodes that are sources of edges with more than two distinct
   labels.

Comment: What do you mean by formally; do you mean as simple logical statements, or as more mathematical statements (this or that function is surjective etc.)?

Comment: All four properties already seem formal enough to me.

Comment: I have taken this question from the book, I have no idea what is meant by formally here....

Comment: Can you please give me the solution to this question that you think would be the right answer by ignoring the word formally...

Comment: The other point is that this is not a website for doing your homework for you. If you do not understand the question at all, then your teacher is a better person to ask.

Comment: This is not my homework, neither I am a student.

Comment: @MishaLavrov if you don't know the answer, just stay away from the post, and let the others help me with the answer.

Comment: You say you are not a student and this is not your homework, but you have posted a question that's just a simple problem statement expecting someone to solve it for you. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) whether or not you are a student.

Comment: @MishaLavrov just tell me what's wrong with my question? Isn't it asked in proper way?

Comment: I have told you what's wrong with it: it is just a problem statement with no context or attempt to solve it. You can click the link for more details.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim kindly assist me...

Comment: @MishaLavrov hala

Comment: @IqraImtiaz I'll type up an answer, but please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question for another time.

Answer (score 0):

The most immediate way of "formally" stating these properties is to reduce them to purely logical ones. I give possible ones here.

1. $\forall x\in L\exists e\in E: \: l(e)=x$ (or said succintly, $l$ is surjective)
2. $\forall n\in N:\: ((\exists e_1,e_2,e_3\in E: \text{target}(e_1)=\text{target}(e_2)=\text{target}(e_3)=a\land l(e_1)=l(e_2)=l(e_3)) \Rightarrow e_1=e_2\vee e_2=e_3 \vee e_3=e_1)$

This one deserves explanation. It says that for any vertex (node) $n$, if there are three edges with $n$ as the target and they all have identical labels, then two of them must be equal - i.e. there does not exist three distinct edges with target $n$. You could also formulate an equivalent statement looking like $\neg(\exists n\in N: \dots)$, but I feel like this is cleaner.

3. $\exists e_1,e_2,e_3\in E: \: \text{target}(e_1)=\text{source}(e_2)\land \text{target}(e_2)=\text{source}(e_3)\land l(e_1)=l(e_2)=l(e_3)$.
4. This is very similar to (2.), and so I encourage you to work this out yourself.